# Use MySQL IF Locate to find 2 different strings

Tags: mysql

I have a query that in part, does this:

```
IF((LOCATE('Linux', LOWER(computers.os)) = 0), 
'Workstation', 'Server')AS 'Machine Type', computers.os AS 'OS version'
```

I want to add to this and assign anything with **either** 'server' **or** 'linux' in the computers.os column and call them servers.

How can I best achieve this?

Thanks for any assistance. Regards Peter.

Okay, a way I might be able to do this is with 'case'

`case computers.os
    when 'server' then 'Server'
    when 'linux' then 'Server'
    else 'Workstation'
end as Machine Type`

But, in this circumstance, nothing will match 'server' or 'linux' precisely. I need to find those strings in the computers.os column. Is there a way I can put like 'server' or contains 'server' into the case statement?

Thanks.

Comment: @Phrancis you might be able to help here

Answer (score 0):

Further digging and testing shows that this will do what I want.

`case
     when computers.os like '%server%' then 'Server'
     when computers.os like '%Linux%' then 'Server'
     else 'WorkStation'
end as 'Machine Type'`